# HTML table - td under another td

Tags: html, html-table

I want to layout my table TDs like the image below.

[image]

I tried a few ways and tried looking up how, but I couldn't get my hands on much. This is the code I have currently. It doesn't work and makes it look like a normal table with all the TDs aligned horizontally. Any tip or clue would be wonderful!

```
<table>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="1">td1</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">td2</td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">td3</td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">td1</td>
        <td>td2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>td3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oou92y33/

Comment: Works like a charm thank you. I thought that if you specified rowspan="2" it would create 2 "rows" in one tr without have to create another tag. Now I know, thank you!